# Dropbox repeatedly keeps popping up "Delete...other items for everyone?" after I delete dropbox folder mounted on Windows 10

Tags: windows, dropbox

I have my dropbox account "mounted" on my Windows 10 PC.

It appears in File Explorer on the left as folder:   Dropbox

When I open this and delete a folder with lots of items, dropbox then pops up the useless and annoying alert (below) over and over.

[image]

Comment: I think what you see is normal for Drop Box. I see the same thing. We are allowed to have 2 installations in the free setup, so I think we all get this. I have Dropbox on computer and phone.

Comment: Well it’s not “useless”, anyone you have shared the file with, will lose access to the file. I assume you click “Delete for everyone”?

Answer (score 0):

This was requested in feature request
[Option to disable delete confirmation popup when deleting online-only files from desktop](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-ideas/Option-to-disable-delete-confirmation-popup-when-deleting-online/idi-p/491829#comments).

The answer by Dropbox Staff member Walter was :

> Thank you for your idea, while we can’t take every idea forward we do
> regularly re-review and will update you if anything changes!
>
> Status changed to: Not for right now

Conclusion : Don't look to Dropbox for a solution.

If this is really bothersome, it's possible to write AutoHotKey macro
to automatically click this button in your place (if this is a solution).